# Hive/Imapala - Execute a Delete Clause: `DELETE from [TABLE] WHERE [CONDITION]`

Tags: hive, overwrite, impala, partition

From browsing the web - I understand that DELETE & UPDATE Clauses are not supported on Impala/Hive. I'm trying to find a workaround for this case.
I tried to perform it with a INSERT OVERWRITE clause with no success :\

I have a partitioned table that contains: user_id, day, month, year 
(Partition on day,month,year).

Say i have 1 row for each date (each date is represented by those 3 partition columns) and i want to delete the row of 2016-05-01

If i used MySQL i would write:

`DELETE FROM tblname
WHERE year = 2016 and month = 5 and day = 1`

How do i perform it on Hive/Impala?

Thank you !

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Partition your data such that the rows (use window function row_number) you want to delete are in a partition . You can then drop the partition without impacting the rest of your table. This is a fairly sustainable model, even if your dataset grows quite large.

detail about Partition .

www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_partitioning.htm

Comment: Thanks! It worked !
I used the `drop partition` that you mentioned:

` ALTER TABLE table_name DROP [IF EXISTS] PARTITION partition_spec, PARTITION partition_spec,...; `


* I didn't used the `row_number` feature cuz my table is already partitioned like i said.

Comment: please http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work